# Convert async computation to .NET task without creating a new thread

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, f#, task

I am learning F# through building an ASP.NET Core app. I need to implement an interface `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore<'TUser>`; this interface features methods that return `Task` like:

```ml
member this.CreateAsync (user : User, cancellationToken : CancellationToken) =
    async {
        let connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("SocialScoreApp")
        let! rowCountResult = user |> createAsync connectionString
        match rowCountResult with
        | Ok _ -> return IdentityResult.Success
        | Error e ->
        let identityError = new IdentityError()
        identityError.Description <- e
        return IdentityResult.Failed(identityError)
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

But, according to the documentation, `Async.StartAsTask` "executes a computation on the thread pool". But this is an I/O bound operation so I don't want any new threads involved. Is there any way to achieve that?

**Edit:** This is the `createAsync` code for reference:

```ml
let createAsync (connectionString : string) (user:User) =
    let sql = "..."
    let args = dict [
        // ...
    ]
        
    async {
        use connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        do! connection.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

        try
            let! rowCount = connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, args) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return Ok rowCount
        with
        | e -> return Error e.Message
    }
```

Comment: Where does C# come into this?

Comment: Sorry, meant to put .NET. Will fix.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. They're essentially the same as an async computation - a *promise* that something will complete in the future. You already use Tasks in the async computation. Asynchronous ADO.NET methods return a Task

Comment: I know tasks aren't threads. But `Async.StartAsTask` does seem to start the computation on another thread according to how I interpret the documentation. If I remove `|> Async.StartAsTask` I get an error, because the return type is `Async<IdentityResult>` instead of `Task<IdentityResult>`

Comment: `Async` and `Task` instances are different regarding when they are run : `Async` is run on demand but `Task` is run immediately. So it's not possible to create a `Task` without the "I/O effect" that bathers you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at how things work, the `StartAsTask` ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/afe8830a7cd259f9a7fd7dcf7f7daeebdad76691/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L907)) operation creates a `TaskCompletionSource`, which creates a task that is returned to the caller. This is later used to report the result of the computation. In the meantime, the computation is started using `QueueAsync`, which invokes `QueueWorkItemWithTrampoline` ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/afe8830a7cd259f9a7fd7dcf7f7daeebdad76691/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L176)) and this uses standard .NET `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

This means that when you run `StartAsTask`, the async workflow is added to the thread pool. However, the key thing for IO-bound operations is that you are using `let!` in your snippet:

```
let connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("SocialScoreApp")
let! rowCountResult = user |> createAsync connectionString
```

The work item added to the thread pool will only run `GetConnectionString`. It will then call `createAsync`, which presumably contains some non-blocking IO operation. As soon as the evaluation gets to this point, the work in the thread pool completes and it schedules a callback to be called when the IO operation completes - the callback is invoked later and adds the rest of the computation to thread pool as a new work item. So, you are not blocking the thread pool while the IO operation is running.

Comment: Thank you Tomas, on spot as always! Added the `createAsync` code for reference.